# Python SQL Error that works on the MySQL Command Line

Tags: python, mysql

I have a python script that reads from a CSV file and inserts the contents into a MySQL database.

When I run my script, this line gives a SQL error:

```
insert_sql = "INSERT INTO billing_info 
                    (InvoiceId, PayerAccountId, LinkedAccountId, 
                    RecordType, RecordId, ProductName, RateId, 
                    SubscriptionId, PricingPlanId, UsageType, Operation, 
                    AvailabilityZone, ReservedInstance, ItemDescription, 
                    UsageStartDate, UsageEndDate, UsageQuantity, 
                    BlendedRate, BlendedCost, UnBlendedRate, UnBlendedCost, 
                    ResourceId, Engagement, Name, Owner, Parent) 
            VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, 
                    %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
```

I get this SQL error when it runs:

```
['198715713', '188087670762', '200925899732', 'LineItem', '200176724883754717735329322', 'AWS CloudTrail', '300551402', '214457068', '34915176', 'EUC1-FreeEventsRecorded', 'None', '', 'N', '0.0 per free event recorded in EU (Frankfurt) region', '2019-03-01 00:00:00', '2019-03-01 01:00:00', '4.0000000000', '0.0000000000', '0.0000000000', '0.0000000000', '0.0000000000', '', '', '', '', '']
Exception: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, ' at line 1
```

But when I take that exact SQL statement that the error is complaining about, and insert it into the database myself, it works!

```
mysql> INSERT INTO billing_info (InvoiceId, PayerAccountId, LinkedAccountId, RecordType, RecordId, ProductName, RateId, SubscriptionId, PricingPlanId, UsageType, Operation, AvailabilityZone, ReservedInstance, ItemDescription, UsageStartDate, UsageEndDate, UsageQuantity, BlendedRate, BlendedCost, UnBlendedRate, UnBlendedCost, ResourceId, Engagement, Name, Owner, Parent) VALUES ('198715713', '188087670762', '200925899732', 'LineItem', '200176724883754717735329322', 'AWS CloudTrail', '300551402', '214457068', '34915176', 'EUC1-FreeEventsRecorded', 'None', '', 'N', '0.0 per free event recorded in EU (Frankfurt) region', '2019-03-01 00:00:00', '2019-03-01 01:00:00', '4.0000000000', '0.0000000000', '0.0000000000', '0.0000000000', '0.0000000000', '', '', '', '', '');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

What the heck could be going on?

Here is all of my code (it's very small):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import mysql.connector
import csv
source = os.path.join('source_files', 'aws_bills', 'march-bill-original-2019.csv')
destination = os.path.join('output_files', 'aws_bills', 'test_out.csv')
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user='xxx', password='xxx',
                            host='xxx',
                            database='aws_bill')
cursor = mydb.cursor()
def read_csv_to_sql():
    try:
        with open(source) as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            next(csv_reader)
            insert_sql = "INSERT INTO billing_info (InvoiceId, PayerAccountId, LinkedAccountId, RecordType, RecordId, ProductName, RateId, SubscriptionId, PricingPlanId, UsageType, Operation, AvailabilityZone, ReservedInstance, ItemDescription, UsageStartDate, UsageEndDate, UsageQuantity, BlendedRate, BlendedCost, UnBlendedRate, UnBlendedCost, ResourceId, Engagement, Name, Owner, Parent) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            for row in csv_reader:
                print(row)
                cursor.execute(insert_sql.format(row))
                mydb.commit()
            print("Done importing data.")      
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception:", e)
        mydb.rollback()
    finally:
        mydb.close()

def main():
    read_csv_to_sql()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure what a python `.format()` does, but I assume its like a `sprintf()` but will it add the single quotes around the `%s`'s ?? Or do you have to code that like `'%s','%s', .....`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I wanted to write the same. Anyway string interpolation/concat could lead to SQL Injection

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Try to do this **cursor.execute(insert_sql,row)**

Comment: When you print the request in the terminal, is it the same as the one that works?

Comment: Thanks!! That was it. I had to use cursor.execute(insert_sql,row) instead of what I had. Also as to leaving it wide open to SQL injects I am very new at this. I will learn from that link that was given.